# The integral $\int_0^1 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \frac{1}{[(x_1+ \cdots +x_n)(1-x_1- \cdots -x_n)]^\alpha},$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Does anyone see a way to compute the integral

$$\int_0^1 dx_1 \cdots dx_n \frac{1}{[(x_1+ \cdots +x_n)(1-x_1- \cdots -x_n)]^\alpha},$$

where $n$ is a positive integer, and $\alpha$ is real/ The limits to all variables are from $0$ to $1$.

I have tried writing $x_1+A$ (grouping $A=x_2 + \cdots x_n$) and performing the $x_1$ integral, but I can't seem to find a closed form solution.

EDIT:

I have tried utilizing Beta functions. For instance, for $n=1$ the integral is equal to

$$B(1-\alpha,1-\alpha).$$

One can go on, but I get terms like $B(n,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ (this is the [incomplete Beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html)). I have also asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640451/incomplete-beta-function-b-na-b-in-terms-of-b-1a-b) question, about whether I can relate $B(n,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ to $$B(1,\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$$.

Comment: Have you tried partial fractions?

Comment: No, because I'm working with general $m$ so I don't know how I would go about it. Is there a closed formula for taking the integrand apart, for general $m$?

Comment: At present, the $-1$ in the denominator is trouble.  Should it be $+1$, or perhaps $x_{n-1}$?

Comment: Are you sure you meant to change $+1$ to $-1$?

Comment: Yes, much to my dismay as well, I need the -1 case unfortunately

Comment: *For instance, for $n=1$ the integral is...* - nope. It would be if there were $1-x_1$, not $x_1-1$. The way it's written *now*, it has $[\ldots]^\alpha$ where "$\ldots$" can be negative. Is it what's really intended?

Comment: you are right, I meant modulo some phase. I'll change it to be more clear

Comment: You can use the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) to simplify the integral a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what the integration domain is. If it is *really* supposed that *all* variables are ranging from $0$ to $1$, then $1-x_1-\ldots-x_n$ gets negative when all of $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are close to $1$ (provided $n>1$), and complex numbers enter the picture. I suspect that the integration domain is really the simplex $$0<x_1,\ldots,x_n,x_1+\ldots+x_n<1.$$

If that suspicion is right, then our integral $$I=\int\limits_{\substack{0<x_1,\ldots,x_n\\x_1+\ldots+x_n<1}}\frac{dx_1\cdots dx_n}{[(x_1+\ldots+x_n)(1-x_1-\ldots-x_n)]^\alpha}$$ can be evaluated using the substitution $y_k=x_1+\ldots+x_k$ ($1\leqslant k\leqslant n$); the Jacobian is $1$, thus $$I=\int\limits_{0<y_1<\ldots<y_n<1}\frac{dy_1\cdots dy_n}{[y_n(1-y_n)]^\alpha}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^1\frac{y^{n-1}\,dy}{[y(1-y)]^\alpha}=\frac{\mathrm{B}(n-\alpha,1-\alpha)}{(n-1)!}$$ after "inner" integration over $y_1,\ldots,y_{n-1}$ under $0<y_1<\ldots<y_{n-1}<y_n:=y$.